# Vue.JS Unit Testing - Original method is still being called after using sinon.stub()

Tags: typescript, vue.js, karma-runner, sinon, sinon-chai

I am using Sinon to stub API calls when unit testing my components (written with TypeScript and [`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)). After adding the stub to the unit test, the original method is still being called (not returning the stubbed value).

```
it('should set the text to bar', async () => {

  const stubbedApiResponse = () => {
    return 'bar';
  };

  sinon.stub(MyComponent.prototype, 'getFoo').callsFake(stubbedApiResponse);

  let options = {
    template: '<div><my-component></my-component></div>',
    components: {'my-component': MyComponent},
    store: this.store
  };
  this.vm = new Vue(options).$mount();

  Vue.nextTick(() => {
    expect(this.vm.$el.querySelector('.text').textContent).toBe('bar'); // Still equals 'foo'
  });
});
```

The method that I am attempting to stub is called on `mounted` in the component and sets the text content. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a min git repo for debug?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, when using TypeScript classes with `vue-class-component`, the `methods` live inside the `options` property of the exported class so, to stub a method, you have to do it like this:

```
sinon.stub(MyComponent.options.methods, 'getFoo').callsFake(stubbedApiResponse)
```

In case your test passes doing that change, ignore everything below.

---

I see a couple of unrelated problems in the code:

- When using PhantomJS, then there's no point in using `async` since `Vue.nextClick` won't use `Promises` anyway; it's simpler to use the `done` function provided by mocha:

  ```
  it('...', (done) => {
    // ...
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      // ...
      done()
    }
  }
  ```
- chai's `be` is a chain and doesn't test for equality; `equal` should be used, eg: `expect(foo).to.equal('bar')`.
- It's better to leave `vm` as a variable instead of a property to avoid referential headaches:

  ```
  const vm = //...
  nextTick(() => { expect(vm.$el)//... }
  ```

Comment: I should've mentioned this in the initial post (besides the tag), but I'm using Typescript and the Vue class component decorator, so the methods aren't inside `methods`. They are just instance methods on the class.

Comment: Updated answer, taking in account typescript classes.